AS400 SUBDUR Command
I'm trying to compile a simple program, just to check how SUBDUR works. But every time I execute the CRTBNDRPG command. It says

"Compilation has been stopped. An error with severity 30 has been
found in the program."

I have been trying to figure out what I did wrong, but I can't. Could someone help me point out my mistake and how to possibly fix it?


The compilers generate an extensive compiler log to the standard print queue qprint. Please run the wrkoutq command to clean old entries and watch where your compiler output goes to.

I needed to declare the data definition for the RES parameter. After declaring the program worked.
